# How to add # to URL in AJAX popup - Magnific Popup Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question , i use Magnific popup plugin but i really want when I click to link which send me to ajax popup to add #newwindow to the URL for example when i click in Magnific site http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ to ajax popup i want to have on my site link like - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup#newwindow. Do you know maybe how to add this ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay First of all thank you for your reply !:) Listen when i have code like this to open only modal window :
js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',

    fixedContentPos: false,
    fixedBgPos: true,

    overflowY: 'auto',

    closeBtnInside: true,
    preloader: false,

    midClick: true,
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
});
```

});

here is HTML :

```
 <a href="#small-dialog--third" class="works-btn popup-with-zoom-anim">Multimedia </a>
                        <div id="small-dialog--third" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
```

i have no idea how to put here call back function to add to URL #small-dialog--third do you know maybe how to do this?